# combine vb with excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

how can i get cell text value from excell sheet in visual basic and then after changing its text send it to back excell. when i open excel file i should get the changed value in file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to Excel and import the following

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Then there is some code [here](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/ExcelObject.aspx) to get you started.